# How is China's version of the revolving door different from that of the U.S.?

Tags: china

> Political risk for Chinese companies has increased significantly,
> according to Zeren Li, whose doctorate studies at Duke University
> focused on China's much more limited version of the "revolving door" —
> the American practice of regulators and lawmakers flipping back and
> forth between working for government and working for the lobbying
> industry.

https://www.cnbc.com/2021/08/19/lobbying-china-firms-cant-influence-government-like-us-companies-do.html

I was reading this article and I was wondering how China's version of the "revolving door" between the private and the public sector was different to America's version of the revolving door and what made it much more limited? Is there some restrictive law in China that prevents to whom an ex-official can work for in the private sector and why is it much more limited?

> Under current law, government officials who make contracting decisions
> must either wait a year before joining a military contractor or, if
> they want to switch immediately, must start in an affiliate or
> division unrelated to their government work. **One big loophole is that
> these restrictions do not apply to many high-level policy makers, like
> Mr. Aldridge, who can join corporations or their boards without
> waiting.**

https://web.archive.org/web/20081022061807/http://query.nytimes.com/gst/fullpage.html?res=9F07E2DC1538F93AA15755C0A9629C8B63

It seems in the United States there's almost no restriction on what company you can work for and when you can do so, but in China I am wondering how different it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some differences comes to mind:

- *the American practice of regulators and lawmakers flipping back and forth between working for government and working for the lobbying industry*  That is largely a factor of people having government job when their party is in power, and not when they lose an election.  The Chinese government does not hold real elections for high office and, when people do fall out of favor, they may not be at liberty to take a job in industry.
- The Chinese government has already mandated a fair bit of control over companies, by forcing most companies to have a [Party council](https://www.chinabusinessreview.com/fact-sheet-communist-party-groups-in-foreign-companies-in-china/).
- China has a lot of [really rich people in its parliament](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/03/02/chinas-parliament-has-about-100-billionaires-according-to-data-from-the-hurun-report.html).  I *assume* many of those are company executives.

So there is a fair bit of mingling, but not necessarily of the same nature as we see in the US and Western countries.

Comment: Also, China's revolving door is more about someone make a big mistake > the party need to maintain stability and sacked him/jailed him > after a while the situation stabilized and people lost interests in this case > he got back out: http://politics.people.com.cn/n/2015/0628/c1001-27218867.html. Translate the last two paragraphs